# pandas - how to merge tables with multiindexes

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two tables that have similar multiindex structure: `date` and `country__name`. Indexes are not identical: some of the countries might be missing from one or another table.

The tables have different columns. To illustrate, here they are:

[image: One] 
[image: two]

I want to merge them into one table that keeps the multiindex but has all the columns from both tables.

But when I do

```
pandas.concat([grouped_channel_df, grouped_tds_df], axis=1)
```

I get a table full of `NaN`:

[image: result]

what am I missing?

Comment: Do you try: `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)`?

Comment: @Serenity yep, this is what happened http://prntscr.com/ex0onh , column names just disappeared

Comment: Then try `pd.merge(df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index(),how='outer',on=['date','country_name']).set_index(['date','country_name']))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to merge table you need to use `.merge` instead of `.concat`. Check the difference between both concepts [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)

For your use case, try something like this:

```
merged = pandas.merge(grouped_channel_df, grouped_tds_df, how='outer', on=('date','country_name'), suffixes=('_channel','_tds'))
```

Read the documentation above to read other options an